# How to create Custom URL Slug in Cake PHP editable from backend

Tags: php, cakephp, slug

i would like to customize url slug from back end for my seo purpose. rigt now what is my status here in application means .

the url slug automatically detect title and set the title as it is

problem is i dont want this auto set url i just want to customize each and every post url

please guide me any one

1. what all are the thing need to be add in view file for that

2  what all are the thing need to be add in controller file

3. what all are the thing need to be add in model file for that

4, Database already have field in name of slug do i need to create any new ??

5. how to conqure and setup all

please give me some solution

Answer (score 1):

1. Add in your db table **slug** field VARCHAR 255
2. Add in your form slug field
3. Save
4. Use Html helper and create links with slug

   ```
   $this->Html->link(
   'title here',
   array('action' => ' view', $article['Article']['slug']));
   ```
5. in Controller [findBySlug](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#magic-find-types)

Comment: already slug is there it auto map to the title of the post

what i need is  i need to set custom url link from back end tell me  the procedure or steps for it

Comment: Are you need just custom slug or url full link ?